# Transitioning from Oracle based CMS to MySQL based CMS

Tags: project-management, database, cms

We're looking at a replacement for our CMS which runs on Oracle. The new CMSes that we've looked at can in theory run on Oracle, but

- most of the vendor's installs run off of MySQL
- vendor supports install of their CMS on MySQL, and a "theoretical" install on Oracle
- the vendor's dev shops use MySQL
- none of them develop/test against Oracle

Our DBA team works exclusively with Oracle, and doesn't have the bandwidth to provide additional support for a highly available and performing MySQL setup. They could in theory go to training and get ramped up, but our time line is also short (surprise!).

So ... I guess my question(s) are: If you've seen a situation like this, how have you dealt with it? What tipped the balance either way? What type of effort did it take? If you're to do it over, what would you do differently ... ?

Thanks!

KM

Comment: What CMS are you thinking of?

Comment: @Nifle It is a Drupal based build, based on Drupal core 6.x. Sorry, I can't be specific beyond that at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using PostgreSQL. It is the open-source version of Oracle and is used enough on the web that most MySQL projects can support it easily. My guess is that the CMS runs on PHP since 90% of them do. In that case, PHP PDO library makes handling the response from a MySQL or PostgreSQL [database the same](https://github.com/Xeoncross/1kb-PHP-MVC-Framework/blob/master/classes/db.php). That leaves you with only one main problem - changing MySQL's tick (`) characters into SQL standard double quotes (").

Since MySQL is mostly used as a datastore - moving to PostgreSQL would give you the Oracle power that you could slowly add into your app where you need it. However, in the beginning you would probably just have to drop all the cool database stuff your team knows - and treat the database as a data dump (you will have to do this with MySQL anyway).

Comment: I think you mean PostgreSQL is "the open-source *equivalent* of Oracle".  Saying "the open-source version" raises the impression that PostgreSQL is based on the same code as Oracle.

Comment: Thanks @Xeoncross. The problem still remains for us: We (DBA team) still have to transition to another RDBMS, and the DBAs have to ramp-up to it, and run it, day-to-day be it MySQL or PostgreSQL. Have you done such a transition? What was your experience like?

Comment: @KM01 As a developer, DBA is not really my specially. However, when I moving my projects off of MySQL an onto PostgreSQL I still had to spend a couple days to figure out how some of the things worked. However, Oracle is much closer to PostgreSQL so things like sequences should be nothing new to you. PostgreSQL is a better choice than MySQL if you value your data.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just have a prototype? Say get another server running PostgreSQL or MySQL and start translating your schema to that db while your oracle is running. QA the hell out of your PostgreSQL or MySQL server and then start to run that server live and kill the Oracle one.

I suggest using PostgreSQL over MySQL. MySQL is own by Oracle and it's gimped as hell compare to Oracle or Postgresql. No roll up with Cubic, it doesn't have certain set function either.

Maybe I'm just reading this wrong. I don't see why this is so hard? The only problem you're going to have is the schema, datatypes or special built in db functions you're using in your schema, maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Thanks @mythicalprogrammer. I guess what we're trying to balance is our Oracle expertise with the vendor's official support matrix. We (DBAs) have in-house expertise in Oracle and not MySQL. The new CMS vendors support the app on MySQL, but say in theory it "can run" on Oracle. They'll support it on Oracle, but we're not sure what happens if there are complications with Oracle based setup. Does that help? I like your idea of a PostgresSQL prototype.